# sql combining two tables with different layout MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm fairly new to sql and I need help combining two tables that have different layouts. Here's an example of what I have. My first table is:

```
Employee's of Jim Data

|year| retired | Other
|2013|   23    | 32
|2014|   12    | 5
|2015|   13    | 8
```

My Second table is:

```
|Director| retire 2016 | retire 2017| Other 2016 | Other 2017|
| tony   |.............|............|............|...........|
| Jim    |    23       |    54      |   12       |     22    |
```

I want my resulting table to have the same layout as "Employee's of Jim Data" (My first table) and it'll append the data from my second table where Director= "Jim". So it should look like this:

```
|year| retired | Other
|2013|   23    | 32
|2014|   12    | 5
|2015|   13    | 8
|2016|   23    | 12
|2017|   54    | 22
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two different queries to get comparable data from those two tables, then use `union all` to merge the results

```
/* from the first table */
select  year, retired, Other
from    table1
union all
/* from the second table */
select  '2016', retire_2016, other_2016
from    table2
where   Director = 'Jim'
union all
select  '2017', retire_2017, other_2017
from    table2
where   Director = 'Jim'
```